# Making a conditional for table view buttonpress

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I have a table view and don't know how to access the row number when the user presses one of the cells. The data of the table view is a small array and this is the closest I could come... In the IB, I control dragged the reusable cell to the view controller I push which works fine. I am unsure how to get the row number in a conditional like this...

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
 {
// A bunch of stuff is before this, but not important to the question
//-- > This line if([indexPath row] == 1) This doesn't work... any ideas?
{
    if(totalPoints < 10 && number != 0)
    {
        [self saveNumber:@"1"];
    }
    else if (totalPoints < 10 && attachment == 0)
    {
        [self saveData:@"1"];
        int newPnts = totalPoints + 1;
        [self savePoints:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", newPnts]];
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `indexPath.row`?

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't work it's strange

Comment: indexPath.row should work. Show the code where you tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",indexPath.row);

        if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Do Somthing..");
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"Do Somthing..");
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I created a dummy project and that worked so it's something wrong with my data sync then...

Answer (score 1):

the row number is [indexPath row] . in tableview you have a dataSource which save the data array used to reload table

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was doing something wrong elsewhere and the view controller doesn't update it's label from the saved data. I will post a seperate question if you're interested